# how to parse the JSON response in the Custom tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, ios7

My structure of JSON is

```
   {"Offer_Stag1":
   [{
   "Area":"1200م2",
   "HotlineNumber1":"12345678",
   "HotlineNumber2":"12345678",
   "Image":"almithaq.mawaqaademo.com\/AlMithaqOfferThumbImages\/19d92aa8-fbc7-49fc-9ebe-a4bdc641216b.jpg",
   "LargeImage":"almithaq.mawaqaademo.com\/AlMithaqOfferThumbImages\/81ecfc05-8431-4ce7-8ac9-5e93c24d7deb.jpg",
   "SectionNo":"184","Stage":"Stage1",
   "TheDetails":"موقع مميز، على مدخل المرحلة الاولى، قريبة من الخدمات\u0009","TheView":" البحرية 17 متر"
    },
    {"Area":"1205م2 – 1201م2",
    "HotlineNumber1":"12345678",
    "HotlineNumber2":"12345678",
    "Image":"almithaq.mawaqaademo.com\/AlMithaqOfferThumbImages\/9cdcab19-49f8-4ad8-a42c-f5e9df273320.jpg",
    "LargeImage":"almithaq.mawaqaademo.com\/AlMithaqOfferThumbImages\/bca29ff9-e6f3-4554-8a8c-9f685ceb9ba6.jpg",
    "SectionNo":"581-582",
    "Stage":"Stage1",
    "TheDetails":"أرضين متلاصقتين، سكة جانبية","TheView":"البحرية 16 متر"
   }]
   }
```

i have customized  table cell want to parse it, hlep me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.itemshowdetailsAr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

-(void)yourmethodName
{
aray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"yoururlname.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"the json resut is %@",JSON);
    aray = [JSON objectForKey:@"Offer_Stag1"];


        for (NSDictionary *tmp in aray) {
        NSMutableDictionary   *itemshowdetails=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

            [itemshowdetails setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"Area"] forKey:@"Area"];
            [itemshowdetails setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"HotlineNumber1"] forKey:@"HotlineNumber1"];
            [itemshowdetails setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"HotlineNumber2"] forKey:@"HotlineNumber2"];
            [itemshowdetails setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"TheDetails"] forKey:@"TheDetails"];
            [itemshowdetails setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"TheView"] forKey:@"TheView"];


            [self.itemshowdetailsAr addObject:itemshowdetails];
        }

    [self.tableView reloadData];  

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
}];

[operation start];
}


#pragma mark - tablevie data source

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

return [self.itemshowdetailsAr count];

}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];




if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;


}



  cell.textLabel.text = [[self.itemshowdetailsAr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectForKey:@"Area"];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.itemshowdetailsAr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectForKey:@"HotlineNumber1"];
 ....
 ....
 .....
return cell;

 }
```

Comment: @Anub.Karthik: Thanks For your post, but it's suggesting AFHTTPRequestOperationManage than AFJSONRequestOperation ?

Comment: both are comes under the AFNetworking format, and both are performing the same functions, if u need AFHTTPRequestOperationManage only  try sebastien FCT answer, but is your choice , everything is used for time optimization,

Comment: OKay thanks , and what it tmpar? in the above code

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this. This is not the exact solution and you'll have to work around your way.

```
NSString *link =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourServiceURL"];
    NSString *encdLink = [link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:encdLink];
    NSData *response = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
```

Now you have your data in the array and extract it out using objectForKey or valueForKey.You can use `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` as per your requirement.

This is what I am doing to fetch images from JSON and showing in my app. Firstly get the array from the above code. Then extract out the image content like this :

```
_demoArray = [json valueForKey:@"yourKeyField"];
```

Now you have the values in your demoArray.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for u post , i'm using AFNetwork framework

Comment: Ohh. In that case, You need to try something else. Edit your post and write about AFNetwork Class or else similar posts might keep coming.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you fetch your `JSON array` with `AFNetworking` in a similar way:

```
-(void)makeRequest
{           
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myServer.com"]];  
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //AFNetworking asynchronous url request
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_enter(group);

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        // You parse your JSON array
        NSDictionary *fullResponse = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
        fullResponse = responseObject;

        if ([[fullResponse objectForKey:@"status"] intValue]  == 1) {
            NSDictionary *successResponse = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
            successResponse = [fullResponse objectForKey:@"success_response"];

            NSArray *offer_Stag1 = [[Nsarray alloc] init];
            Offer_Stag1 = [successResponse objectForKey:@"Offer_Stag1"];

            allObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for (int i = 0; i < [offer_Stag1 count]; i++){
                NSDictionnary *singleObject = [offer_Stag1 objectAtIndex:i];
                [allObjects addObject:singleObject];
            }

        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];

    [operation start];

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // Here you call the desired method after all data have been downloaded, typically you should reload your tableView
        [self.myCustomTableViewWithDataFromServer reloadData];   
    });

}
```

Some explanation:

- First you fetch your server
- You parse your `JSON object` into `NSDictionnary` or `NSarray` (or combination of both)
- You encapsulate your `AFNetworking request` with a dispatched group in order to reload your `UITableView` after all data have been downloaded.

Then, I guess you did it, you can just access your `NSMutableArray` where you stored the data in order to display them in the cells

Your `NSMutableArray` is a global variable:

```
@interface MyCustomController() {
    NSMutableArray *allObjects;
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks for the comment and i'm following this technique. and i want to parse the data to that label, i ve created UILabels for all the data

Comment: I'm getting this error: no visible @interface for 'AFHTTPRequestOperation' declares the selector 'setCompletionBlockWithSuccess' PLS advice

Comment: Let's say you have `UILabel` called "area" for your data "Area". You should find the right index in your `array`: 

In your `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, you should call something like this: 

    NSDictionnary *toDisplay = [allObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
    area.text = [toDisplay objectForKey:@"Area"];

Comment: @A.S.K You should provide your code dealing with `AFNetworking` implementation in order to solve this other issue.